# Binding InkToolbarCustomPenButton Pallete to InkToolbarBallpointPenButton doesn't add colors

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

So, I'm trying the code from here: 
https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/11/22/windows-ink-2-digging-deeper-with-ink-and-pen

And this is the code for the XAML:

```
<CommandBar Name="myCommandBar" IsOpen="True">
    <CommandBar.Content>
        <InkToolbar x:Name="myInkToolbar" TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind myInkCanvas}">
            <InkToolbarBallpointPenButton Name="penButton" />
            <InkToolbarCustomPenButton Name="markerButton" CustomPen="{StaticResource MarkerPen}" Palette="{x:Bind penButton.Palette}" >
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Highlight" />
                <InkToolbarCustomPenButton.ConfigurationContent>
                    <InkToolbarPenConfigurationControl />
                </InkToolbarCustomPenButton.ConfigurationContent>
            </InkToolbarCustomPenButton>
        </InkToolbar>
    </CommandBar.Content>
</CommandBar>
```

But when I click on the palette it only shows black and white. However, when I put this `markerButton.Palette = penButton.Palette` in code-behind upon the click of a button, all colors show. But, if I do this on the `MainPage()` constructor, it doesn't work.

Upon debugging, it shows `penButton.Palette` as `null` but only in the constructor, in the `button_click` method, it works.

So, what gives? How can I bind `InkToolbarCustomPenButton Palette` to `InkToolbarBallpointPenButton Palette`?

And here's my code-behind file:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Debug.Write(penButton.Palette.Count); // this doesn't write anything and produces palette as null
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Write(penButton.Palette.Count); // this produces 30
    markerButton.Palette = penButton.Palette;
}
```

Edit: here's the link to a test sample reproducing the same issue:
https://github.com/dydx-git/Ink2Demo

Comment: You need to get  `penButton.Palette` after   `this.InitializeComponent(); in the MainPage  constructor. Because `InitializeComponent` method used to init xaml component.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: Could you share mini sample testing for us?

Comment: sure! just edited the post

Comment: Or do you mean putting the solution on GitHub? Let me know 'cause I can do that as well. Anything that helps :)

Comment: The better way is post your demo on github share us with link, and I will test base on your demo.

Comment: I'll do that soon

Comment: Ok, I will check tomorrow.

Comment: Hi, here you go: https://github.com/dydx-git/Ink2Demo

Comment: hi, I checked your code and solve  the issue please check the following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Binding InkToolbarCustomPenButton Pallete to InkToolbarBallpointPenButton doesn't add colors.

The problem is you used x:bind to get penButton's `Palette`(lazy load), but the default model of x:bind is one time. For solving this issue please 
remove `markerButton.Palette = penButton.Palette` this line from `MainPage` construction and edit your xaml like following.

```
<InkToolbarCustomPenButton Name="markerButton" CustomPen="{StaticResource MarkerPen}" Palette="{x:Bind penButton.Palette,Mode=OneWay}" >
    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Highlight" />
    <InkToolbarCustomPenButton.ConfigurationContent>
        <InkToolbarPenConfigurationControl />
    </InkToolbarCustomPenButton.ConfigurationContent>
</InkToolbarCustomPenButton>
```

Comment: It was so obvious. Thank you!